# Automatically verifying gdrive app login in python program

Tags: google-drive-api

I want to automatically verify my credentials without going to the link and pasting the verification code every time I run this program.

might storing credentials will work but I don't know how to store it and reuse it..

my code is given below

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import httplib2
import pprint

from apiclient.discovery import build
from apiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
from oauth2client.client import OAuth2WebServerFlow
from oauth2client.file import Storage



# Copy your credentials from the console
CLIENT_ID = 'my_id' #i have client id but dont wanna share
CLIENT_SECRET = 'my_secret' #i have client secret but dont wanna share

# Check https://developers.google.com/drive/scopes for all available scopes
OAUTH_SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'

# Redirect URI for installed apps
REDIRECT_URI = 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob'

# Path to the file to upload
FILENAME = 'hello.txt'

# Run through the OAuth flow and retrieve credentials
flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, OAUTH_SCOPE,
                           redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI)
authorize_url = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
print 'Go to the following link in your browser: ' + authorize_url
code = raw_input('Enter verification code: ').strip()
credentials = flow.step2_exchange(code)

# Create an httplib2.Http object and authorize it with our credentials
http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)

drive_service = build('drive', 'v2', http=http)

# Insert a file
media_body = MediaFileUpload(FILENAME, mimetype='text/plain', resumable=True)
body = {
  'title': 'My document',
  'description': 'A test document',
  'mimeType': 'text/plain'
}

file = drive_service.files().insert(body=body, media_body=media_body).execute()
pprint.pprint(file)
```

any help is appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find the documentation on OAuth with python: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_oauth (edited url)

basically you will have to use `self.redirect(authorize_url)` to make that step automatically and then in the second step you will use `flow.step2_exchange(self.request.params)`

In the documentation will find a better explanation of the process.

Comment: have you verified ? actually I don't want to use browser for any kind of verification as i m trying to make script that will take backup of folder and upload it to Gdrive without verification.

Comment: sorry, i posted a wrong url. the one i just edited goes to the documentation i mentioned.